# Django String trimming breaks encoding using truncatechars template tag

Tags: django, python-3.x, templatetag

this is the text used to trim in the list view

```
my_var = une  startup (jeune pousse, société )
```

and use this template tag for trimming

```
 {{my_var | striptags | truncatechars:"50" }}
```

I got this output

```
une  startup (jeune pousse, soci&eacu...
```

expected out is : `une  startup (jeune pousse, socié...`

but got some unexpected output....

Comment: This is not a problem with the template. The variable's contents is converted to HTML entities before being passed to the template, somewhere in your code. That said, there's no way to handle this with standard filters (truncatechars_html is *tag* aware but **not** *entity* aware).